# Does Jasmin SMS tool have API's I can consume to extend and build my desired SMS gateway service?

Tags: c#, docker, sms, smpp, jasmin-sms

Am an intermediate software engineer.. I am designing and working towards building an SMS gateway service. P.S this would be in a distributed microservices environment. So it would run as docker container .

I wish to use Jasmin installed as docker 
However my concerns are how I can perform functions usually done from the jcli over an API.

Like create default or static route and rate, create a connector, create a group , add a user to group. create processing filters and intercepting processes that would run before before message sending..

I wish to know if there are apis I can consume as to perform this actions.. as against directly performing such on a cli environment.

**P.S.**
I have gone through the documentation in the docker section.. installed and spin the docker container, create default route , group and user and BUT by telnet and use of the jcli .. even successful sent  a message.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in API available in Jasmin to use JCLI directly. However if you are looking for something GUI based then you can try this project
[Jasmin Web Panel](https://github.com/jookies/jasmin-web)

I have used this and It works perfectly.